# Sum with different condition for every line

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

In my Postgresql 9.3 database I have a table `stock_rotation`:

```
+----+-----------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
| id | quantity_change | stock_rotation_type | article_id |        date         |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 |              10 | PURCHASE            |          1 | 2010-01-01 15:35:01 |
|  2 |              -4 | SALE                |          1 | 2010-05-06 08:46:02 |
|  3 |               5 | INVENTORY           |          1 | 2010-12-20 08:20:35 |
|  4 |               2 | PURCHASE            |          1 | 2011-02-05 16:45:50 |
|  5 |              -1 | SALE                |          1 | 2011-03-01 16:42:53 |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
```

Types:

- `SALE` has negative `quantity_change`
- `PURCHASE` has positive `quantity_change`
- `INVENTORY` resets the actual number in stock to the given value

In this implementation, to get the current value that an article has in stock, you need to sum up all quantity changes since the latest `INVENTORY` for the specific article (including the inventory value). I do not know why it is implemented this way and unfortunately it would be quite hard to change this now.

My question now is how to do this for more than a single article at once.

My latest attempt was this:

```
WITH latest_inventory_of_article as (
    SELECT MAX(date)
    FROM stock_rotation
    WHERE stock_rotation_type = 'INVENTORY'
)
SELECT a.id, sum(quantity_change)
FROM stock_rotation sr
INNER JOIN article a ON a.id = sr.article_id
WHERE sr.date >= (COALESCE(
                     (SELECT date FROM latest_inventory_of_article),
                     '1970-01-01'
                 ))
GROUP BY a.id
```

But the date for the latest `stock_rotation` of type `INVENTORY` can be different for every article.
I was trying to avoid looping over multiple article ids to find this date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would use a different internal query to get the max inventory per article. You are effectively using stock_rotation twice but it should work. If it's too big of a table you can try something else:

```
SELECT sr.article_id, sum(quantity_change)
FROM stock_rotation sr
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT article_id, MAX(date) AS date
    FROM stock_rotation
    WHERE stock_rotation_type = 'INVENTORY'
    GROUP BY article_id) AS latest_inventory
    ON latest_inventory.article_id = sr.article_id
WHERE sr.date >= COALESCE(latest_inventory.date, '1970-01-01')
GROUP BY sr.article_id
```

Comment: This even accounts for the case that there are articles without a stock_rotation of type INVENTORY, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT ON` together with `ORDER BY` to get the latest `INVENTORY` row for each `article_id` in the `WITH` clause.

Then you can join that with the original table to get all later rows and add the values:

```
WITH latest_inventory as (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (article_id) id, article_id, date
    FROM stock_rotation
    WHERE stock_rotation_type = 'INVENTORY'
    ORDER BY article_id, date DESC
)
SELECT article_id, sum(sr.quantity_change)
FROM stock_rotation sr
    JOIN latest_inventory li USING (article_id)
WHERE sr.date >= li.date
GROUP BY article_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it: First, build the list of products at their last inventory state, using a window function. Then, join it back to the entire list, filtering on operations later than the inventory date for the item.

```
with initial_inventory as
(
select article_id, date, quantity_change from
(select article_id, date, quantity_change, rank() over (partition by article_id order by date desc)
from stockRotation
where type = 'INVENTORY'
) a
where rank = 1
)
select ii.article_id, ii.quantity_change + sum(sr.quantity_change)
from initial_inventory ii
join stockRotation sr on ii.article_id = sr.article_id and sr.date > ii.date
group by ii.article_id, ii.quantity_change
```